# Drop column range starting with first column matching regex

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyselect

I have the following dataframe, which is the output of `read_excel` with missing column names in excel:

```
t <- tibble(A=rnorm(3), B=rnorm(3), "x"=rnorm(3), "y"=rnorm(3), Z=rnorm(3))
colnames(t)[3:4] <-  c("..3", "..4")
```

How can I select columns `..3` to `Z` in a flexible dynamic way (not depending on number or table width). I was thinking in the direction of something like:

```
t %>% select(-starts_with(".."):-last_col())
```

But this gives a warning, since `starts_with` returns two values.

Comment: Not an answer - but it may be easier to rename the columns using ``dplyr::rename_at()``, since col names in the form of "..j" are invalid.

Comment: Maybe `t %>% select(-starts_with("..")[1]:-last_col())` ?

Comment: Just to clarify, your expected output is columns A and B, right? We are wanting to exclude all cols starting from .. column to the last column?

Comment: @zx8754 yes, thank you, dumb me. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could force to select the first one:

```
t %>% select(-c(starts_with("..")[ 1 ]:last_col()))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       A      B
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 0.889  0.505
# 2 0.655 -2.15 
# 3 1.34  -0.290
```

Or "tidier" way use *first*:

```
select(-first(starts_with("..")):-last_col())
```

Comment: I have modified it as `select(-first(starts_with("..")):-last_col())`

Comment: @c0bra great, added your option, too, definitely tidier compared to my base approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using base R:

```
t[cumsum(startsWith(names(t), "..")) == 0]

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       A       B
#   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 -1.56 -0.0747
# 2 -1.68 -0.847 
# 3 -1.23 -1.20
```

Which you could also use with `select()`:

```
t %>% 
  select(which(cumsum(startsWith(names(t), "..")) == 0))
```

PS. Don't use `t` as a variable name in R since it is a function name.